# Remove digits in CSV headers

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file that has been converted from a dict - witch has added Numbers to get the columns unique. Now I want to remove the numbers.

Example of CSV headers now:

```
User,Comment,Comment1,Comment2,Created
```

I would like to use something like this:

```
header = ''.join([i for i in header if not i.isdigit()])
```

I uses this code to create the CSV without any empty columns.

```
with open('input.csv') as fd, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as fdout:
    rd = csv.reader(fd)
    cols = set()
    _ = next(rd)  # skip header line
    for row in rd:
        for i, val in enumerate(row):
            if val != '':
                cols.add(i)
    _ = fd.seek(io.SEEK_SET)
    wr = csv.writer(fdout)
    for row in rd:
        _ = wr.writerow(val for i, val in enumerate(row) if i in cols)
```

And my desired output are the same file but headers like this:

```
User,Comment,Comment,Comment,Created
```

Comment: What is your desired output? By the way, you don't need to do `_ = ` to assign things you don't even use.

Comment: My desired output in csv are:
User,Comment,Comment,Comment,Created

Comment: Does the header also have empty values or just the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Python's [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=itemgetter#operator.itemgetter) which can be used to extract just the required values from each row.

If your header only contains numbers at the
start or end, a simple approach is to use `.strip('0123456789')` to remove them.

```py
from operator import itemgetter
import csv
import io

with open('input.csv') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    header = next(csv_input)

    # Test the first row for empty values
    first_row = next(csv_input)
    required_cols = itemgetter(*(index for index, value in enumerate(first_row) if value))
    
    f_input.seek(io.SEEK_SET)   # restart
    header = next(csv_input)
    csv_output.writerow(value.strip('0123456789') for value in required_cols(header))
    
    for row in csv_input:
        csv_output.writerow(required_cols(row))
```

For example, if the CSV contained the following:

```
User,Comment,Comment1,Comment2,Created
Fred,a,b,,11-02-2022
Wilma,a,b,,11-02-2022
```

The `Comment2` column would be completely removed and also the digits from the header giving:

```
User,Comment,Comment,Created
Fred,a,b,11-02-2022
Wilma,a,b,11-02-2022
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like

```
import csv
import re

with open("input.csv") as fd, open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as fdout:
    rd = csv.reader(fd)
    wr = csv.writer(fdout)
    # read header line, remove trailing numbers from each column
    header = [re.sub(r"\d+$", "", col) for col in next(rd)]
    # write processed header out
    wr.writerow(header)
    for row in rd:  # just copy other lines
        wr.writerow(row)
```

should do the trick, then.

Comment: Damn my man! huge thanks to you for you kind effort!!!